# E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TControl.Color how do I get around that?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Why does Delphi 10 Architect give this error?

I want to change the `Color` property of a shape through the `OnMouseMove` event. But it gives me this error:

> E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TControl.Color

Is there any way around that?

````pascal
var
  TrafficLights: TTrafficLights;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTrafficLights.btn1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  shp1.Color := clRed;
end;

procedure TTrafficLights.btn2MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  shp2.Color := clYellow;
end;

procedure TTrafficLights.btn3MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  shp3.Color := clGreen;
end;                                                                                             ```
````

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory. The `Color` property is `protected` in the `TControl` base class. Derived components decide whether or not to promote the property to `public` or `published` as needed.

Case in point, `TShape` does not promote `Color` for public access. You need to use the `Brush.Color` property instead, eg:

```pascal
shp1.Brush.Color := clRed;
shp2.Brush.Color := clYellow;
shp3.Brush.Color := clGreen;
```